# 'Assertive' package not on CRAN

Tags: r, package, cran

I tried installing the assertive package and got this error message:

```
'Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘assertive’ is not available for this version of R A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere'
```

I looked on CRAN and it says 'Package ‘assertive’ was removed from the CRAN repository' (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/assertive/index.html)

I'm using the most updated version of R Studio (RStudio 2023.12.0+369) and R. How can I get this package? It is a dependency for another one so I really need it...

Comment: As per the link, you can download an archived version of the package in the link shown there.  Do make sure to first install the `assertive.properties` package first, as it's indicated to be a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

To Expand on Phil's reply:

1. `install.packages("devtools") # you need to install devtools to access the packages that arent on cran any more # google helped me find the source for assertive ...`
2. `devtools::install_bitbucket("richierocks/assertive") # (this failed because assertive as a bunch of other dependencies that need to be installed)`

I got the following error: (which is what Phil's reply explained)
ERROR: dependencies 'assertive.properties', 'assertive.types', 'assertive.strings', 'assertive.datetimes', 'assertive.data', 'assertive.data.uk', 'assertive.data.us', 'assertive.code' are not available for package 'assertive' * removing 'C:/Users/leoki/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/assertive'

3. `devtools::install_bitbucket("richierocks/assertive.properties") # install this one first! (other's depend on it)`
4. `devtools::install_bitbucket("richierocks/assertive.types") # I then tried each of these`
5. `devtools::install_bitbucket("richierocks/assertive.strings")`

I soon got bored and installed all the remaining dependencies in one line:

6. `devtools::install_bitbucket(c("richierocks/assertive.datetimes", "richierocks/assertive.data", "richierocks/assertive.data.uk", "richierocks/assertive.data.us", "richierocks/assertive.code"))`
7. `install_bitbucket("richierocks/assertive")`

I was actually after drop2 so I finally collected that using:

8. `devtools::install_github("karthik/rdrop2")`

I hope this works for others too