# Deploying a shiny app on shinyapps.io with a bitbucket repo dependency

Tags: r, shiny, web-applications, bitbucket, shinyapps

## Problem Definition

I have a shiny app that relies on a number of packages mainly from CRAN. Some of the packages have been installed from publicly available bitbucket repos eg:

```
devtools::install_bitbucket("richierocks/assertive.properties")
devtools::install_bitbucket("richierocks/assertive.types")
```

...there are others too.

The app works great locally but when I go to deploy the app on shinyapps.io, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: child_task=1392178012 child_task_status=failed: Error parsing manifest: Unknown repository for package source: bitbucket
Execution halted
```

Seemingly shinyapps.io can't install a publicly available bitbucket package as it can't see the source. Is there a way to add this 'package source' so that it can be seen by shinyapps.io and then the packages can be installed when the app is being deployed?

## Context

In thinking about solutions, it might be helpful to know context of this problem. My app uses the [rdrop2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rdrop2/index.html) package which provides access to the dropbox API and its quite central to the apps functionality. This is [no longer being maintained](https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2) it seems and so it is no longer on CRAN. So now I need to install rdrop2 from github (`devtools::install_github("karthik/rdrop2"))`, but this also requires that a bunch of `assertive` dependencies also be installed manually [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77719426/assertive-package-not-on-cran). That's the bigger picture of my problem in case it helps inspire anyone to think of a workaround.

Comment: Based on this [Github Issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rsconnect/issues/88) it appears like you don't any type of command to explicitly install a package.  You simply load it and the `rsconnect::deployApp()` function detects what needs to be installed and where to get them.

Comment: Well it would if all dependencies were on CRAN and github but the problem seems to be that the dependencies are on bitbucket. [See this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rsconnect/issues/333). The link at the bottom of that issue is to a shinyapps doc that says "Currently, the shinyapps.io service supports deploying packages installed from CRAN, GitHub (both public and private repos), and BioConductor." So I think the problem is that I am using `bitbucket`. I wonder if can can download the packages and deploy them with the app. Messy solution but I'm stuck on this.

Comment: The most expedient way is to pull the repos and upload to GitHub.